# Длинное слово - первое

Tags: c, строки

Нужно определить самое длинное слово в строке и поменять его местами с первым.
Если слов с максимальной длиной несколько, менять следует первое из них.

**Input**
Со стандартного устройства ввода вводится строка, соседние слова в которой разделены одним пробелом. Длина текста не превышает 1000 символов.

**Output**
Нужно выдать на стандартное устройство вывода измененную строку.

**Sample Input**

Hi here, Man !!!

**Sample Output**

here, Hi Man !!!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 1000
#define M 1000
int main()
{
    char arr[1000][M] = {0};
    char str[N],
        tmp[N],
        result[N];
    char sp[] = " ";
    int count = 0,
        max = 0;
    
    int i = 0;
    fgets(str, N - 1, stdin);
    strcpy(tmp, str);
    
    char* token = strtok(str,sp);
    
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        count = strlen(token);
        strcat(arr[i++], token);
        
        if (count >= max)max = count;
        
        
        token = strtok(NULL, sp);
    }   
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (strlen(arr[j]) == max)
        {
            char tmp_str[M];
            strcpy(tmp_str, arr[0]);
            strcpy(arr[0], arr[j]);
            strcpy(arr[j], tmp_str);
        }
        
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf( "%s%s", arr[j], j < i - 1 ? " " : "" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как думаете, почему работает только на 90%?

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам требуется помощь с тем, чтобы найти ошибку в коде, то прикладывайте к вопросу входные данные,  вывод программы и вывод, который ожидался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в условии сказано, что если слов с максимальной длинной несколько, то следует менять первое из них.

А во 2 цикле вы если находите слово с максимальной длинной, то меняете его с первым словом и не выходите из цикла, а дальше ищите остальные слова с максимальной длиной.

То есть если у вас будет несколько слов с максимальной длиной, то у вас будет вместо первого слова, последнее с максимальной длиной.

Вам нужно выходить из цикла, как только вы поменяли местами слова, например так:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    if (strlen(arr[j]) == max)
    {
        char tmp_str[M];
        strcpy(tmp_str, arr[0]);
        strcpy(arr[0], arr[j]);
        strcpy(arr[j], tmp_str);
        break;
    }
}
```

Но лучшим решением будет во время нахождения слова с максимальной длиной, сохранить его индекс в массиве слов.

Например так:

```
int maxI = 0;
while (token != NULL)
{
    count = strlen(token);
    strcat(arr[i], token);
  
    //Заметьте, что тут строгое сравнение т.к.
    //нужно первое слово с максимальной длинной
    if (count > max) {
        max = count;
        maxI = i;
    }

    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, sp);
}
```

И тогда не нужен цикл, а просто заменяете первое слово на слово с индексом `maxI`:

```
char tmp_str[M];
strcpy(tmp_str, arr[0]);
strcpy(arr[0], arr[maxI]);
strcpy(arr[maxI], tmp_str);
```

Полный код со всеми изменениями и немного комментариев [код](https://ideone.com/6riuC6)